# CodeIgniter, all pages except the homepage have status code 404, but look perfectly fine?

Tags: php, codeigniter

The only reason I noticed this is because I tried to do an ajax call, and my callback was never called. Because I got back a 404, even though it worked fine and the response was correct. Also I can't send any POST data, it gets wiped out. Has anyone heard of this? What extra information do you need from me?

I'm on localhost, WAMP. And using virtual hosts

Comment: @StephensenSarcsamKamer how you are making that AJAX call??

Comment: Doesn't matter. This happens everywhere. If I go to `mysite.com/home/index` the same thing happens. Everything looks fine, but if I open chrome dev tools and look at the http code it's 404. Every page is 404, but they all look fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. I didn't have mod_rewrite installed... somehow.

And this part of my htaccess was allowing it to work with 404 status codes

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for answering the question. would have taken me ages had you not pointed it out :)